# Convergence of a complex series at the boundary of a region of convergence.

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

I'm having trouble understanding how to calculate if a complex series converges in the boundary of a certain region. For example, if given:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(z+2)^{n-1}}{4^{n}(n+1)^{4}}
$$
I can get with the ratio test that the series converges when $$|z+2|<4 $$
but how can I know the convergence at $ |z+2|= 4$?
I know that in real numbers we just put the number in and use another criteria, but with complex numbers the given condition is the modulus and not the exact number.

Comment: The absolute value is always non-negative. It cannot be $-4$ or any negative number.

Comment: And what happenes in $+4$?

Comment: You can easily check that the series converges on the boundary: $$
\left| {\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{(z + 2)^{n - 1} }}{{4^n (n + 1)^4 }}} } \right| \le \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{\left| {z + 2} \right|^{n - 1} }}{{4^n (n + 1)^4 }}}  = \frac{1}{4}\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{(n + 1)^4 }}}  <  + \infty .
$$

Answer (score 1):

If $|z+2|=4$, then$$\left|\frac{(z+2)^{n-1}}{4^n(n+1)^4}\right|=\frac1{4(n+1)^4}.$$Since the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{(n+1)^4}$ converges, your series converges absolutely, and therefore it converges.

Comment: What if in a case that it does not coverge absolutely? For example $$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(z+2)^{n-1}}{4^{n}(n+1)}
$$

Comment: That's another question. I suggest that you post it as such.